# Перемещение программы без заголовка на рабочем столе

Tags: c#

Как можно перемещать программу на рабочем столе, если установить formBorderStyle = none?

Comment:     http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread528141.html
    http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread43629.html
    http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Sources.aspx?id=1037&mode=show



Answer (score 5):

Тут есть два обычных подхода:

- перекрыть WndProc так, чтобы клик по форме воспринимался как клик по заголовку,
- отслеживать клик по форме и движения мыши и менять координаты формы самостоятельно.

Пример второго подхода.

```
private bool isDragging = false;

private Point lastCursor;
private Point lastForm;

private void Form_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    isDragging = true;

    lastCursor = Cursor.Position;
    lastForm = this.Location;
}

private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (isDragging) {
        this.Location = 
            Point.Add(lastForm, new Size(Point.Subtract(Cursor.Position, new Size(lastCursor))));
    }
}

private void Form_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    isDragging = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чуть короче:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Координаты мышки
    private int x = 0; private int y = 0;

    // Нажатие кнопки мышки
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x = e.X; y = e.Y;
    }
    // Движение мышки
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Location.X + (e.X - x), this.Location.Y + (e.Y - y));

        }
    }
 }
```